# MSUnit Testing Async Hell

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, mstest

I have an `async Task` unit test (MVC, c#, .NET 4.5.2).  It does an `await` on a `aysnc Task<ActionResult>` method, which in turn has an `await` call on a async method.

The test, and others like it, will pass if I select them and choose `Debug Selected Tests` from the right-click menu in Visual Studio 2017.

The problem is when I select `Run Selected Tests` or `Run All`.  It is then that many of the tests will fail if they follow the condition mentioned at the beginning.  Any test that only returns a `RedirectToRouteResult` without having gone the aforementioned drill-down will pass.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestPartsController_GetPartInfo_ReturnsInfo()
{
   //arrange
   PartController pc = new PartController();

   //act
   var result = await pc.GetPartInfo("PC123456");

   //assert
   Assert.IsIntanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
   Assert.AreEqual("Form", ((ViewResult)result).ViewName);
   Assert.AreEqual("PC123456", result.Model.PartNum.ToUpper());
}

public async Task<ActionResult> GetPartInfo(string partNum)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partNum)
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index")
   }

   var response = await ServiceClient.GetJsonAsync("/part/partinfo", "?partNum=" + partNum;
   response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   results = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dto.PartNumInfo>();
   ...
   return View("Form", model);
}

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(Controllers controller, string criteria)
{
   HttpClient client;
   string service = GetService(controller, out client);
   var response = await client.GetAsync(service + criteria);
   return response;
}
```

***Solution***
Use async/await all the way through as well as using statements and IDisposable.

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJsonAsync<T>(Controllers controller, T data)
 {
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    using (var service = new MyService())
    {
       HttpClient http;
       string serviceLoc = service.GetServiceClient(controller, out http);
       response = await http.GetAsync(serviceLoc, data);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Comment: _It is then that many of the tests will fail_ Can you provide some details about how they fail? Also, I have a hard time figuring out the meaning of _if they follow the condition mentioned at the beginning_. What does _the condition_ refer to?

Comment: They fail by not being able to continue drilling down into the async methods.  The condition is what is mentioned in the first paragraph.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not an edit to the question. You can then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution Use async/await all the way through as well as using statements and IDisposable.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJsonAsync<T>(Controllers controller, T data)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    using (var service = new MyService())
    {
       HttpClient http;
       string serviceLoc = service.GetServiceClient(controller, out http);
       response = await http.GetAsync(serviceLoc, data);
    }

    return response;
}
```